# How to deploy a lite and pro version to the android market?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

From other posts I learned, that I need a base library project and two app projects deriving from the lib to have a free and pro version of my app. I also learned, that it is not possible to have the same package name in the market to offer two different versions of an app. My question is now how to offer a free and a pro version of the (almost) same app in the market, so that the free version can be replaced by the pro version. An option would be an unlocker project that enables pro features but I prefer an installation of either the free version with later upgrade or directly install the pro version. I also like the approach of the two projects based on the lib and would like to avoid to change that concept.

Any help is welcome

regards, Ramin

Comment: If you already know that to create a free and pro version you can use a library project + two app projects using that library, then what's your question? I wouldn't recommend trying to have the pro installation replace your free one, but you *could* try to import your data.

Comment: As shown above, my question is how to upgrade from MyAppFree to MyAppPro. Why do you not recommend to replace the free by the pro version since this is exactly my goal? Who should be interested to keep the free version after buying the pro version?